# Filter array of object to get only properties which have same value in all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```
const myArr = [
  { name: "john", id: 1, age:10 },
  { name: "john", id: 2, age:10 },
  { name: "mary", id: 3, age:10 }
];
```

Desired output: `{age:10}`,
as only age is common in all.
I want this in Javascript.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

> The `reduce()` method executes a user-supplied "reducer" callback function on each element of the array, in order, passing in the return value from the calculation on the preceding element. The final result of running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single value.

**Demo:**

```js
function getCommonProperties(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((commonProp, obj) => {
    //iterate over the properties of the current obj
    for (const prop in obj) {
      //check if the property in all objects
      if (arr.every(item => item.hasOwnProperty(prop) && item[prop] === obj[prop])) {
        //if same, add it to the commonProp object
        commonProp[prop] = obj[prop];
      }
    }
    //return the object
    return commonProp;
  }, {});//set The initial value as an empty object
}

const myArr = [
  { name: "john", id: 1, age: 10 },
  { name: "john", id: 2, age: 10 },
  { name: "mary", id: 3, age: 10 }
];

const res = getCommonProperties(myArr);
console.log(res); //{ age: 10 }
```